# MySql statement not working in .bat file but works fine in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a .bat file with the following code in it

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 
5.7\bin\mysql.exe" -u root  -p88adb88 -h localhost -Ddatabase_1 -e 
"delete from job where id in (select * from (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM job 
where job.created_date between (select CURDATE() +Interval 60*60*3 second) 
and (select CURDATE() + INTERVAL (60*60*24-1) SECOND) GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) as dup)"&pause"
```

But it doesn't work. It deleted all records created in the period defined. Not the duplicated ones. It is supposed to delete the jobs with job count more than 1. However the delete statement works perfectly in MySql workbench. 
One interesting thing is when I do not give space between "COUNT(*)>1" and the closing bracket")", the .bat file does not even execute.

Can somebody please help

Thanks a lot in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem by putting the SQL delete statement in a separate text file. And change the .bat code, using "< deleteDuplicate.txt" to replace the delete statement in the .bat code. It worked well. However, I still don't know what caused the problem if put sql statement in the .bat file.